# Removing vertices or lines within polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, vertices

I have transformed a *.dxf*-file into a polygon shapefile. In many of the polygons I have lines which do not belong there but I can not delete them as I normally delete vertices on polygons by selecting it and pressing the delete key.

Here is an image (the lines which I want to delete are circled in red).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Those lines and vertices are actually holes or islands on your polygon.

Try using the delete part or delete ring tools in the advanced digitizing toolbar, and click on one of the nodes. I have noticed that sometimes you need to drag one or more nodes a bit to  be able to click on the hole\island boundaries to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Such holes can often occur when you merge polygons (depending on the data quality). There is a tool called `delete ring` on the `Advanced Digitizing` toolbar. Select it and then click near (depending on your snapping presets) one of the nodes around the "hole". This will delete the ring.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should first use the node tool to move vertices to show the hole and then use the remove hole tool and click inside the hole.

Answer (score -2):

Use select tool in QGIS. It provides a lot of options. select by feature, freehand, radius, etc. See the image below.you can then delete the selected features. you need to toggle editing of layer before selecting

[image: qgis_select].